# C# how do I this simple else to loop until true?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a hangman game, this part of the code goes behind the button new game. Everytime the user selects new game I want the game to load a new word for users to guess. My problem is I need to put my code in to a loop. For example if non of the if/else statements are not true, select another random number until a statement is true...

I hope that make sense =) Here's my code so far.

```
namespace HangMan
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int RW;
    string previous;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBox textBox in addTextBox())
        {
            textBox.Visible = false;
            textBox.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private static void LoadImages()
    {
        Image newImageIntro = Image.FromFile("HangmanIntro.jpg");
        Image newImage1 = Image.FromFile("1.jpg");
        Image newImage2 = Image.FromFile("2.jpg");
        Image newImage3 = Image.FromFile("3.jpg");
        Image newImage4 = Image.FromFile("4.jpg");
        Image newImage5 = Image.FromFile("5.jpg");
        Image newImage6 = Image.FromFile("6.jpg");
        Image newImage7 = Image.FromFile("7.jpg");
        Image newImage8 = Image.FromFile("8.jpg");
        Image newImage9 = Image.FromFile("9.jpg");
    }

    private void txtEnText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtEnText_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

public List<TextBox> addTextBox()
    {
        List<TextBox> tBox = new List<TextBox>();

        tBox.Add(textBox1);
        tBox.Add(textBox2);
        tBox.Add(textBox3);
        tBox.Add(textBox4);
        tBox.Add(textBox5);
        tBox.Add(textBox6);
        tBox.Add(textBox7);
        tBox.Add(textBox8);
        tBox.Add(textBox9);
        tBox.Add(textBox10);

        return tBox;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rW = new Random();

        foreach (TextBox textBox in addTextBox())
        {
            textBox.Visible = false;
        }


        RW = rW.Next(1, 4);

        if (RW == 1 & previous != "1" ) //Cat
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            previous = "1";


        }
        else if (RW == 2 & previous != "2" ) //Elephant
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
            textBox5.Visible = true;
            textBox6.Visible = true;
            textBox7.Visible = true;
            textBox8.Visible = true;
            previous = "2";
        }
        else if (RW == 3 & previous != "3") //Giraffe
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
            textBox5.Visible = true;
            textBox6.Visible = true;
            textBox7.Visible = true;
            previous = "3";
        }
        else if (RW == 4 & previous != "4") //Monkey
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
            textBox5.Visible = true;
            textBox6.Visible = true;
            previous = "4";
        }
        else
        {
        }



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Glen where is the loop..?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Comment: Ahh, I need to put the code into a loop... but wasn't sure how to, I was thinking maybe I could do a do { while but then I have to put something in the while() parenthesis but I don't know what

Comment: @GlenHunter Well, the best thing to start with is go and look at the documentation on For, foreach, and while loops and make sure you understand those first.  That should help get you started and then you could refine your question.

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your code?

Comment: 2nd time today i see a hangman question, seems like the same homework :-)

Comment: You might also want to use short-circuit `&&` rather than `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this around your code:

```
while(true)
{
// CODE
break;
}
```

and inside the `else {}` part:

```
continue;
```

Edit:
You can also use LINQ, e. g.

```
while(Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(t => !t.Visible))
```

if you only have those boxes whose visibility changes inside the loop.

Comment: This is a pretty ugly code construct.  I'd avoid using it.  Better to just loop while the integer is not valid, and then proceed knowing it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through the checks, try looping until you get a random number you like.

Here is some pseudo code on how you could do something like that.

```
//while the next random number is not the same as the previous
    //Generate a new random number
```

once you have a random number you like, you wont have to check for the previous number in those ifs.

You might also want to look up the documentation for the switch statement, as it might make your code more readable here.